# Is there any HTML CSS or JavaScript click through property?

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop

For example on a drag and drop scenario.. I would love to be able to use the onmouseover of the thing we are dragging to, but unfortunately, the design calls for a ghost (copy of what is being dragged) which will surround the area of the mouse pointer. So the cursor is moused over the ghost the whole time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Firefox 3.6+, Chrome and Safari, you can use `pointer-events: none;`

- [jsfiddle.net Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6Y7pT/)
- [Original Post from pixelastic.com](http://www.pixelastic.com/blog/198%3aclick-html-element)

> When one HTML element is over another one (like when positioning an
>   element using `position:absolute`), you usually can't click through the
>   top element to access the bottom element.
>
> That's used as a common
>   technique to prevent the right click on images by some sites (like
>   Flickr). They just add an empty transparent div over their images to
>   prevent the lambda user from right clicking and saving the image.
>
> Sometimes, when integrating complex designs, you need those additional
>   layers, but you also want the user to be able to click through them,
>   as if they weren't there.
>
> Just use the `pointer-events:none` css
>   property to allow click events to go through the element.
>
> This is only
>   supported by Firefox 3.6+, Chrome and Safari for now.

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to use jQuery? If so, I would look into jQuery UI to handle both your drag and drop events. Since you can make a ghost copy of what you are dragging without disrupting where you drop it.

Visual feedback for drag allowing you to show a fake ghost copy.
- http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback

Visual feedback for when you hover over the droppable area.
- http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#visual-feedback